# SQL Group By with Count is slow

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

I have a table with close to 3 million rows that has 5-10 updates/inserts every second. Each row is assigned a category, and I want to group by the category to count the total number of rows for each category.

```
Select CategoryId
     , COUNT(*) as TotalRows
  FROM Table1
 WHERE SaleTypeId = 2 AND CategoryId > 1
 GROUP BY CategoryId
```

Table Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table1](
[SaleId]      INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[SaleTypeId]  INT                 NOT NULL,
[CategoryId]  INT                 NULL)
```

Primary Key:

```
 ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_Table1] 
 PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([SaleId] ASC) 
 WITH (ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, PAD_INDEX = OFF, 
       IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF);
```

I have a non-clustered index on the table:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [Index1] ON [dbo].[Table1]
(
    [SaleTypeId] ASC,
    [CategoryId] ASC    
)
```

Query Plan:

[image]

The query takes 40 to 60 seconds to run, and it looks like a lot of data is being read in the index seek operation. Is there any way to speed up this query? I have read that count gets slower on bigger data sets and that there are quicker ways to get the count of an entire table, but I need to get the count by the category.

Comment: Adding a clustered index would definitely help.

Comment: The diagram shows that the index seek is happening on Table1.Index1 which is not idx_SaleCategory. Looks like you aren't getting the benefit of your new index.

Comment: @M.Ali - it would help _this query_ but may be a BAD choice of clustered index overall.

Comment: @M.Ali There is a clustered index, I'll include it in the question. sarin, that's due to the anonymization tool with SqlSentry, I'll update the naming.

Comment: You could also try adding `WITH NOLOCK`.  You may be experiencing contention if you get multiple updates a second.

Comment: check this article http://www.sqlservergeeks.com/articles/sql-server-bi/49/indexing-for-aggregates-in-sql-server - it will definitely help you

Comment: Use COUNT(CategoryId) instead of COUNT(*).

Comment: @DaveJemison This doesn't seem to make a difference. The execution plan appears the same and the number of reads don't change. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Not sure how many columns you have in the table. It probably won't make much difference with just a few.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up running this as a nightly aggregate job and storing the result in an aggregate table. It doesn't provide up to date results (which, after deliberation, we can live with) nor is the nightly query any faster, but reading from the aggregate table is a lot faster.

Answer (score 1):

Reverse the columns order in the nonclustered index, like this:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [Index1] ON [dbo].[Table1]
(
    [CategoryId] ASC,    
    [SaleTypeId] ASC
)
```

Comment: why do you recommend this? From what I understand, equality columns should be used first in the index, followed by inequality columns. When I run the query with the reversed index, the execution plan recommends creating the original index.

Comment: Have you looked at the index to see if it's heavily fragmented and needs rebuilding?

Comment: I recommended it because `SaleType = 2` doesn't seem very selective. Not nowing the actual density it was worth trying. The thing is that you must read (in order) a large portion of index, one or the other; no other way to count aggregate on CategoryId, In any case there should be an NC index on those two columns, which one is just a matter of selectivity.

Comment: Gotcha. So it seems I'm out of luck? I know that count can be slow, but this seems like a trivial thing to do.

Comment: @DaveJemison The index does get fragmented, but it's defragged nightly. The execution plan in the question is when it's run right after a defrag.

Answer (score 0):

Try running this, I would also put index as @dean suggested

```
Select CategoryId, COUNT(CategoryId) as TotalRows
 FROM Table1 WITH (NOLOCK)
 WHERE SaleTypeId = 2 AND CategoryId > 1
 GROUP BY CategoryId
```